# pgadmin3 doesn't detect postgres

Tags: server, postgresql, pgadmin

I successfully installed and downloaded pgadmin and postgresql.  When I boot pgadmin3, The interface comes up successfully, but I can't see postgres, or any other servers.

I tried changing `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`, but it didn't change anything.

If I try to create a server group with the name `postgres` and the correct password, I get this `Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774742/pgadmin3-server-connection-and-authentication-error), I realized that I needed to set the host to 127.0.0.1.

I guess you learn these things as you go.